# Android: When creating a tab to display an RSS feed should a new layout be created?

Tags: java, android, rss

Im creating a workout app for myself and some friends and have decided to add an RSS feed in one of the tabs. I have no experience dealing was rss so have a couple questions before I dive in:

As my app contains 3 tabs should I create the rss view on a separate xml layout ? or can I create it on my main xml layout ?

Can anyone recommend any good rss reader tutorials?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can learn parse xml. And list it with ListFragment.

http://www.androidpit.com/java-guide-2-program-your-own-rss-reader

And you can learn work with Swipe Views with Tabs http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html